# Salesforce Dataloader id value of incorrect type

Tags: data-loader, csv

I am having this issue with dataloader. I am doing an insert and I get an error:

```
 id value of incorrect type: ABCD
```

Where ABCD is my value. I have 2 custom objects  and CustomObject2. CustomObject2 has a field which is a lookup relationship to CustomObject1. I have looked online and I know I need to pass the ID to this lookup field in my csv file. However since it is an insert I do not have the ID. How would I insert my value ("ABC") in this lookup field?

Comment: If you are trying to `insert` records and you have an `Id` column, simply do not map that column. What are you trying to achieve here? Why are you trying to insert records where you already have an Id value? Are you sure it's not supposed to be an External Id field?

Comment: @AdrianLarson I have an auto number field but I do not map that to anything. I don't have an ID field in my csv file. I am trying to insert records into salesforce

Comment: You're mapping something to an Id field and your question doesn't include enough detail to really offer a good answer without some guessing. Remove any field mappings for relationships in addition to making sure you don't map Id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, to be able to link your Child object (custom object 2)  to your Parent object (custom object 1) using the "ABCD" value and not the ID via dataloader you must :

1. Create an **external id** field in the parent object, it's the field that stores your "ABCD" value on the parent.
2. In dataloader, choose the upsert operation for the child object -> you will be asked to choose an external id field to match your child records with parent object records, choose the field you just created.
3. Now, when mapping, you will find a special field called "Parent_object__r:external_id__c"
4. In the mapping, leave the lookup field empty, and match your file column having the "ABCD" value with the special field "Parent_object__r:external_id__c"
5. Salesforce will create your child record and automatically fills the lookup field based on the external id.

Doc : 
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000002783&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.fr%2F&type=1